# What is the set $\mathbb{Q} \ \mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the set $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. It seems like this would simply be {0}. Is there a proof?

Comment: I'd say that $3/4$ is in $\Bbb Q$, is not in $\Bbb N$ and is not $0$.

Comment: Do you mean the set of rationals which are not positive integers? Why wouldn't it contain 1/2?

Comment: Let us break down what the symbols here mean.... $\Bbb Q$ is the set of all rational numbers, including such things as $\frac{3}{8}, 2, \frac{-1337}{249}, -5$ etc...  Meanwhile $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers, $0$ (*if you include that*), $1,2,3,\dots$.  Meanwhile $\setminus$ is the symbol meaning set difference., so what remains is the elements that are in the first set which are not in the second set...

Comment: There are rational numbers that are not whole numbers as well as negative rational numbers.  Is that really what you meant to ask?

Comment: $\Bbb Q\setminus \Bbb N$ is the set of numbers that are rational but not natural, such as $-1$, $1/2$, and many others

Comment: Define the rationals is the ratio of an integer in the numerator and a natural number in the denominator. Then, we mean the set difference of the rationals and the natural numbers. So, can we say that since the natural numbers are required to create the integers and the rational numbers other than zero, that the set difference of the rationals (without) and the natural numbers is just the set containing zero?

Answer (score 1):

It's the set of all rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ ("integer fractions") where we remove ($\setminus$ denotes a set difference) all natural numbers $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. If $0 \notin \Bbb N$, $0$ is still rational so $0 \in \Bbb Q \setminus \Bbb N$ but many more numbers are in that set: $-1,-2$ for starters and also proper fractions like $\frac12$, $\frac{113}{355}$ (and their negatives) etc.

Comment: Define the rationals is the ratio of an integer in the numerator and a natural number in the denominator. Then, we mean the set difference of the rationals and the natural numbers. So, can we say that since the natural numbers are required to create the integers and the rational numbers other than zero, that the set difference of the rationals (without) and the natural numbers is just the set containing zero?

Comment: @Zeta10 no, definitely not. $\frac12$ is in $\Bbb Q$ and is **not** in $\Bbb N$ so is in the set difference: $A \setminus B = \{x\mid x \in A \text { and } x \notin B\}$ by definition.

Comment: I understand the definition of set difference. I think I just need to review how the rationals are generated because the way I have defined them is as a ratio of an integer and a natural number. I suppose the main distinction is that once I have created the ratio from the elements of the latter two sets, I no longer can consider the pieces of it to belong in the natural numbers or integers. Then, each rational number that is negative or has a number other than one in the denominator would still remain. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeta10 a rational should be seen as a totally different thing, not a "derived object" from an integer, which "disappears" if we remove the integers from the set. They're independent things. We can build representations such that $\Bbb N \subseteq \Bbb  Q$, but that is already a minor simplification because we see integers as special fractions, namely those with denominator $1$. (fractions are themselves equivalence classes e.g. $\frac{4}{2}=\frac{2}{1} = 2 \in \Bbb N$..)